# How to set up gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, vps

My django project in `/root/code/mysite`, django apps: main, homepage. What should I write in gunicorn.service? (Debian 9, user root)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please consider checking out [what topics can you ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), this question is actually very unclear and is hard to guess what do you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample systemd service file for my gunicorn service (using unix-socket)

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=user-group
EnvironmentFile=/home-dir/.env-file
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/project
ExecStart=/path/to/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --log-level debug \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          wsgi-file:application --timeout 120 --workers=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Check out [this walkthrough on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)